# SQL Contains extremely slow for single element

Tags: sql, linq

I have the following query (which is build via `linq`) which is a simple `Count` of the elements in `Table1` which are somehow related to an entry in `Table2`. 
This query runs for about 2 minutes.

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C2]
    FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[myFunction]([Extent1].[Table1Id]) AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[Table2Id] IN (cast('02df5a88-b189-4218-8819-2d0a35887d26' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ([Extent2].[Table2Id] IS NOT NULL)
    ))
```

If I add another `Id` to be checked against `[Extent2].[Table2Id]` the query completes in 0.5 seconds.

I already tried to change the `Contains`-call (which gets converted to SQLs `IN(...)`) to `==` in case there is only a single `Id` given - but still the same.
So, for now, I am adding a dump Id in case there is only one given.

What am I doing wrong here?

The `myFunction` SQL-function returns a list of `Table2`-entries for a given `Table1Id` which are self-referencing in order to create a parent-child-relationship, e.g. `Table2.ParentId = Table2.Id`.

This is the linq-query I use (simplified):

```
var ids = new Guid[] {new Guid("14763ded-3a38-43d8-a3e4-b1eb17870136"), Guid.NewGuid()};
Table1.Count(f => (dbContext.myFunction(f.Table1Id)).Any(c => (ids.Contains(c.Table2Id))));
```

Comment: This query seems a bit convoluted, why not Join on Table 1 & 2? It will help to see the layout of the two tables and the Linq you've used to generate the above.

Comment: @StevePy I've added the linq-code. See updated question

Comment: The relationship between table 1 & 2 are key here. Your code is effectively going to need to iterate over every record in Table 1 since there is no direct relationship with Table 2 given that is where the condition is being applied. I'm not familiar with the idea of a "function" against the context. At face value I'd probably be looking at constructing a View for this data relationship (Table 1 associations to Table 2 and their ancestry) but I'd need to see the actual table relationship and the problem you are trying to solve.